# How to specify time for a scheduler which runs now and never runs again

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

@Scheduled to execute the method only **once** at the time of deployment by using fixedRate, in the spring application..

Please let me know, I am unable to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Then why annotate the method with Scheduled, simply call it at whichever point of time you choose.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `@PostConstruct` annotation so the method will execute once after the bean's creation. Running the method only once defeats the purpose of the `@Scheduled` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Why to use `@Scheduled` then? You can use [InitializingBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html) or @PostConstruct to execute your process.

Comment: Initially I've used @PostConstruct, but want to remove that.Because of some other problem.

Comment: If you explain the problem than that can be resolved. You could use InitializingBean if you have issues with PostConstruct.